# Edit YAML file with Bash

Tags: python, bash, awk, sed, yaml

I'm trying to edit the following YAML file

```
db:
  host: 'x.x.x.x.x'
  main:
    password: 'password_main'
  admin:
    password: 'password_admin'
```

To edit the `host` part, I got it working with

```
sed -i "/^\([[:space:]]*host: \).*/s//\1'$DNS_ENDPOINT'/" config.yml
```

But I can't find a way to update the password for `main` and `admin` (which are different values).

I tried to play around with `\n` and `[[:space:]]` and got different flavours of:

```
sed -i "/^\([[:space:]]*main:\n*[[:space:]]*password: \).*/s//\1'$DNS_ENDPOINT'/" config.yml
```

But never got it to work.
Any help greatly appreciated!

**Edit** - Requirement: no external binaries/tools. Just good ol' bash.

Comment: You should consider using a YAML parser like `yq` Can you install such a tool?

Comment: I would prefer to avoid doing that. Not a requirement, but almost.

Comment: Agreed, whatever options you are going to use with standard text processing tools aren't going to be reliable

Comment: Okay, let's say it's a requirement. As far as I know `yq` is a wrapper around `jq`, so it should be possible to do that reliably.

Comment: So there are two versions of `yq` available. One using `jq` and other using a proper DSL, written in Go. The former -https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/, the latter -  https://github.com/mikefarah/yq. Depends on which one you want to use

Comment: Remember that sed != bash, so whatever approach you are taking, custom flags/regexes might work on one system and fail in another

Comment: "_Requirement: no external binaries/tools. Just good ol' bash._" - but you are using `sed` yourself?

Comment: `Just good ol' bash` would be a terrible choice. If you can't use `yq` then you should instead use one of the standard tools you can call from a shell, e.g. awk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ awk -v new="'sumthin'" 'prev=="main:"{sub(/\047.*/,""); $0=$0 new} {prev=$1} 1' file
db:
  host: 'x.x.x.x.x'
  main:
    password: 'sumthin'
  admin:
    password: 'password_admin'
```

or if your new text can contain escape sequences that you don't want expanded (e.g. `\t` or `\n`), as seems likely when setting a password, then:

```
new="'sumthin'" awk 'prev=="main:"{sub(/\047.*/,""); $0=$0 ENVIRON["new"]} {prev=$1} 1' file
```

See [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script) for why/how I use `ENVIRON[]` to access a shell variable rather than setting an awk variable in that second script.

Answer (score 20):

Since you don't want to install `yq` you could use [python](/questions/tagged/python) that you most probably already have installed.

Here are the fundamentals:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import yaml

with open("config.yml") as f:
    y = yaml.safe_load(f)
    y['db']['admin']['password'] = 'new_admin_pass'
    print(yaml.dump(y, default_flow_style=False, sort_keys=False))
```

Output:

```yaml
db:
  host: x.x.x.x.x
  main:
    password: password_main
  admin:
    password: new_admin_pass
```

A similar piece of [python](/questions/tagged/python) code as a one-liner that you can put in a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script would look something like this (and produce the same output):

```sh
python -c 'import yaml;f=open("config.yml");y=yaml.safe_load(f);y["db"]["admin"]["password"] = "new_admin_pass"; print(yaml.dump(y, default_flow_style=False, sort_keys=False))'
```

---

If you'd like to save the output to a file, you can provide an output stream as the second argument to `dump()`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import yaml

with open("config.yml") as istream:
    ymldoc = yaml.safe_load(istream)
    ymldoc['db']['admin']['password'] = 'new_admin_pass'

with open("modified.yml", "w") as ostream:
    yaml.dump(ymldoc, ostream, default_flow_style=False, sort_keys=False)
```

If you'd like to overwrite the original file, I recommend writing to a temporary file first and only if that succeeds, use `os.rename` to move that file in place of the original one. That's to minimize the risk of creating a corrupt `config.yml` in case of problems.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 You are welcome! It requires some editing to replace the hardcoded strings but it should a pretty good base to use when editing YAML files.

Comment: Very good answer indeed, provide me with the robustness of Python.

Comment: This worked well for me but unfortunately it looks like it only print the updated value but doesn't save the updated file. How can i do this?

Comment: @Jerry I'm glad to hear that it helped. I updated the answer to show how you can save the updated information to file.

Answer (score 8):

**Note:** Using a YAML parser like [`yq`](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) (or [`yq`](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/)) will be a way more reliable solution.

---

However, I've used the following 'technique' to alter a 'pre-defined' line though the help of [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) and [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) like so;

**/tmp/config.yml**

```yaml
db:
  host: 'x.x.x.x.x'
  main:
    password: 'password_main'
  admin:
    password: 'password_admin'
```

1. Get the line number where your 'old-password' is located:

   ```
   grep -n 'password_admin' /tmp/config.yml | cut -d ':' -f1
   ```

   > 6
2. Then, use `sed` to override that line with your new password:

   ```
   sed -i '6s/.*/    password: \'new_admin_pass\'/' /tmp/config.yml
   ```

The new file now looks like this:

```yaml
db:
  host: 'x.x.x.x.x'
  main:
    password: 'password_main'
  admin:
    password: 'new_admin_pass'
```

---

**Note**

- Keep in mind that any special chars (`&`, `\`, `/`) in the password will cause `sed` to misbehave!
- This could fail if the indent changes, since YAML cares about indentation. Just like I mentioned above, using a YAML parser will be a much more reliable solution!

Comment: Thanks! Let's assume the indent does not change. Could something else cause this command to fail?

Comment: @Mornor I dont think so, I've used this 'style' to alter YAML for quite some time now, never failed. However, my YAML file is quite static, I'm only using this technique to alter a password ;)

Comment: It would fail if the new password contained backreference metacharacters like `&` or `\1` or if it contained delimiter chars `/` or escape chars `my\new\pass` or others. As long as your passwords are always strictly alphanumeric you should be OK but if they aren't then YMMV. You don't need grep+cut+sed though - a simple awk script will do the job. Not also that that's relying on you knowing the old admin password when all you really want is to change the admin (or main) password to the new value no matter what it was before.

Comment: ... I just realised it'd also fail if the `main:` password just happened to be the same as the `admin:` password or if that admin password just happened to also show up elsewhere in the file.

Comment: This doesn't consider the tree structure of the yml files. A simple grep will find all the occurrences of the key and not the ones belonging to a particular node. I believe a correct implementation in pure bash would be complicated as it has to read the indentation and then parse the tree structure.

Answer (score 5):

This is by **no way as reliable as `yq`** but you can use this `awk` if your yaml file structure is same as how it is shown in question:

```
pw='new_&pass'
awk -v pw="${pw//&/\\\\&}" '/^[[:blank:]]*main:/ {
   print
   if (getline > 0 && $1 == "password:")
      sub(/\047[^\047]*\047/, "\047" pw "\047")
} 1' file
```

```
db:
  host: 'x.x.x.x.x'
  main:
    password: 'new_&pass'
  admin:
    password: 'password_admin'
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by experts in other answers too, `yq` should be the proper way but in case someone doesn't have it then one could try following.

```
awk -v s1="'" -v new_pass="new_value_here" '
/main:/{
  main_found=1
  print
  next
}
main_found && /password/{
  next
}
/admin:/ && main_found{
  print "    password: " s1 new_pass s1 ORS $0
  main_found=""
  next
}
1
'  Input_file
```

***NOTE:*** In case you want to save output into Input_file itself then append  `> temp  && mv temp Input_file` to above solution.